# How to use atomic 64bit in glsl of OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I try to use atomic functions of glsl for 64-bit integer type, such as atomicCompSwap.

I found some related extensions

- GL_EXT_shader_atomic_int64
  When I try to enable this extenion, I got the following compile error

```
ERROR  Compilation error: 0(16) : error C0202: extension EXT_shader_atomic_int64 not supported
```

- GL_NV_shader_atomic_int64
  This extension can be enabled without error. However, there are some weird compile errors while using atomicCompSwap. Please check the following example codes

```c
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : require
#extension GL_NV_shader_atomic_int64 : require
layout(std430, binding = 0) coherent buffer Test{ uint64_t test; };
void main() {
    uint64_t origin_key = 0u;
    uint64_t key = 1u;
    atomicCompSwap(test, origin_key, key);
}
```

The compile error is

```
error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "atomicCompSwap(uint64_t, u64vec2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is specification for [NV extension](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_shader_atomic_int64.txt).
There are 2 strange details about atomicCompSwap:

1. There are no uint version
2. There are no compare argument in *int64_t atomicCompSwap(inout int64_t mem, int64_t data);*

I had the same problem and found that **uint** version really doesn't exist. But also *atomicCompSwap* has 3 arguments as it should be.

Comment: I fixed the error by adding extension "GL_NV_gpu_shader5".